# Regarding Order of Precedence (c++)

Tags: c++, logical-operators, boolean-expression, operator-precedence

I am reading on C++ and I am going over a section on Order of Precedence.

There is an example that I don't quite understand and that is:

```
11 > 5 || 6 < 15 && 7 >= 8
```

> "This logical expression yields different results, depending on whether || or && is evaluated first. If || is evaluated first, the expression evaluates to false. If && is evaluated first, the expression evaluates to true."

I would appreciate it if someone could explain why would it be true/false in either situation. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where did you get the quotation? In C++, and other languages that have these operators, && *is* evaluated first. No 'if' about it.

Comment: @EJP: `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, but that doesn't mean `&&` is evaluated first.  In this case, `&&` is not evaluated at all.

Answer (score 3):

If the `||` is evaluated first:

```
(11 > 5 || 6 < 15) && 7 >= 8
(true || false) && false
true && false
false
```

If the `&&` is evaluated first:

```
11 > 5 || (6 < 15 && 7 >= 8)
true || (true && false)
true || false
true
```

Answer (score 3):

The precedence of the `&&` and `||` operators is defined by the language, so the "if" in the quoted text doesn't make much sense.

The phrase "evaluated first" is misleading. It's not the order in which the subexpressions are evaluated that matters, it's how the subexpressions are associated with the `||` and `&&` operators.

```
11 > 5 || 6 < 15 && 7 >= 8
```

Since the relational operators have higher precedence than (i.e., bind more tightly than) the `||` and `&&` operators, the above is equivalent to:

```
(11 > 5) || (6 < 15) && (7 >= 8)
```

which in turn is equivalent to:

```
true || true && false
```

As it happens, `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so the above is equivalent to:

```
true || (true && false)
```

which reduces to:

```
true || false
```

which is

```
true
```

On the other hand, *if* `||` had higher precedence than &&`, then

```
true || true && false
```

would be equivalent to

```
(true || true) && false
```

or

```
true && false
```

which is

```
false
```

It's important to know that there really is no option here. The language unambiguously states that `&&` binds more tightly than `||`, so there's no way that `11 > 5 || 6 < 15 && 7 >= 8` could evaluate to `false`.

It happens that, unlike with most operators, the operands of the `&&` and `||` operators are evaluated in strict left-to-right order, with the right operand not being evaluated at all if the value of the left operand is enough to determine the result. This is called "short-circuit evaluation", and it lets you write things like:

```
if (ptr != NULL && *ptr == 42)
```

without fear of dereferencing a null pointer. But that doesn't matter in this particular case, since none of the subexpressions have side effects. The three subexpressions `11 > 5`, `6 < 15`, and `7 >= 8` could be evaluated in any of the 6 possible orders with exactly the same final result.

Answer (score 1):

`&&` has higer precedence than `||`, so there should be no `if`.

`11>5` evaluates to true, and that's the value of the entire expression.  The second operand of the `||` operator, which is `6 < 15 && 7 >= 8`, won't get evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

If `||` is evaluated first, you get `((11 > 5) || (6 < 15)) && (7 >= 8) == (true || true) && false == true && false == false`.

If && is evaluated first, you have `(11 > 5) || ((6 < 15) && (7 >= 8)) == true || (true && false) == true || true == true`.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to explain the following way. Let's forget about the original expression and will use symbolic names **a**, **b** and **c** instead of the relations.

Then we will get two forms of records

```
( a || b ) && c
```

and

```
a || ( b && c )
```

In the first case we have in fact two operands of operator &&. If at least one operand is false then the whole expression is also equal to false. Now let return to the original expression. As **c** corresponds to

```
7 >= 8
```

It is equal to false so the whole expression `( a || b ) && c` is equal to false.

In the second case we also have two operands of operator ||. If at least one operand is equal to true then the whole expression is equal to true. As **a** corresponds to original expression

```
11 > 5
```

that is equal to true then the whole expression `a || ( b && c )` is also equal to true.